# It seems i can't send the message from the form to the div container to show

Tags: javascript, html, css

fresh student with ambition here hope I don't annoy anyone.

i have this html :

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="chat_container"></div>
  <form>
    <textarea name="prompt" rows="1" cols="1" placeholder="Ask Tibi..."></textarea>
    <button type="submit">
      <img src="./send.svg" alt="send" />
   
   
   </form>
```

when i try to submit by pressing either enter or the button in the `div id="chat container"></div>` it dosen't show up

I can't find the error in the javascript code:

```js
const form          = document.querySelector('form');
const chatContainer = document.querySelector('#chat_container');

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);

form.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    handleSubmit(e);
  }
});
```

everything is happening in a folder called client

i also have a directory with others css html js files independent from that folder...i just can't find the error why i can't send the message from the form to the top of the div chat_container...
Any idea? if i need to improve the question please tell me.

i tried most of the tutorials/copy:paste code 1:1 modify the js changing folders

Edit: here i have the full code of handle.submit

```js
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(form);
  chatContainer.innerHTML += chatStripe(false, data.get('prompt'));
  form.reset();
  const uniqueId = generateUniqueId();
  chatContainer.innerHTML += chatStripe(true, " ", uniqueId);
  chatContainer.scrollTop = chatContainer.scrollHeight;
  const messageDiv = document.getElementById(uniqueId);
```

Comment: Does your handleSubmit function have some code that attempts to write to the chat_container div, because I'm not seeing anything that tries to here.

Comment: You are saying, "it dosen't show up" but not showing the code that shows the container. Please show the code of `handleSubmit`, and also it will be helpful to have the code above as a snippet that we can run and see the problem.

Comment: Does `handleSubmit()` call `event.preventDefault()`? If not, the submit bytton will reload the page.

Comment: Please add the `handleSubmit` function definition.

Comment: As you asked, here is function for handlesubmit in a snippet hope it helps. I'm here for any details that i can give

Comment: Your code snippet is still incomplete. Can you provide a minimal example?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: In your HTML, 1. the `<button>` element misses a closing tag.  2. Same for the app div.

In your JS, there's no closing curly bracket for the `handleSubmit` event handler. Also, what's that `chatStripe` variable? It's not defined in your JS snippet